# Where can I find Gold/Gems in Minicraft?

Tags: minicraft

I've explored a fair bit of the underground in Minicraft (one level down) and I can find *nothing* except Iron down there.

Do I just need to keep exploring? Are there stairs going down that I haven't found?

Comment: ...minicraft? What's minicraft?

Comment: @KortPleco Notch's recent entry for Ludum Dare, located [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ld48/ld22/index.html).

Comment: @kevin, ok cool, it sounded like a real game but I had never heard of it before. =)

Answer (score 6):

Gold is in underground level 2.

There is at least 1 down stairs in underground level 1.

There is another one in underground level 2.

Likewise, gems can be found in underground level 3.

If you cant find it (they're really big) on the appropriate level keep searching

Comment: i agree with this post but you can also find gems by killing creepers (pigeoncraft minicraft not sure if in regular)

Answer (score 1):

There are three mine-levels: iron-level (1) gold-level (2) gem-level (3). Gems are in the nether, flooded with lava. Do not touch it, it does 4 damage.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep mining and searching. The lower you go the more valuable the ores are. But for most of them you need atleast an iron pick